# How to write double into file, using filechannel and bytebuffer?

Tags: java

I try to the following  methods, but it seems something wrong.

```
    File f=new File("D:\\aa.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(f);
    FileChannel fc=fos.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
    for (int i=0;i<16;i++) {
        buf.putDouble(i*8,Math.sqrt(i));            
    }
    fc.write(buf);
    fc.close();
```

Comment: Well, "what is wrong"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `flip()` the buffer before writing it, and `compact()` it afterwards if you're looping.

Comment: for (int i=0;i<16;i++) {
            buf.putDouble(i*8,Math.sqrt(i));
        }
        buf.compact();
        buf.flip();
        fc.write(buf);
        fc.close();   Do you means like this? but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I don't mean like that. I said '`flip()` the buffer before writing it, and `compact()` it afterwards'.